# How do you see / show a git merge conflict resolution that was done, given a merge commit SHA1?

Tags: git, merge, resolution, conflict

When you resolve a conflict, then stage the changes, then do a git diff, it shows you two columns of +'s and -'s, one for "ours" and one for "theirs".  Given a merge commit in a repo's git history, how do I see that resolution, which was done by someone else?  In other instances, I've seen it before (in gitk, I think), but I can't seem to determine it for this SHA1 that I have.

Comment: "then do a git diff, it shows you two columns of +'s and -'s, one for "ours" and one for "theirs"" ... it does?  How do you have your git configured?

Comment: @gcbenison: It only does this when you are dealing with a merge conflict, before you have committed your conflict resolution.  I don't think that takes any special configuration.

Comment: With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), `git log --remerge-diff` will show you what you have done in your merge resolution! See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71181334/6309).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you know the ref, then `git show <MERGE_COMMIT>` will show you the resolution done (if any) for the merge commit.

For log, use `git log -p -c` or `git log -p --cc`. From the manpage of git log:

```
   -c
       With this option, diff output for a merge commit shows the differences from each 
       of the parents to the merge result simultaneously instead of showing pairwise 
       diff between a parent and the result one at a time. Furthermore, it lists only 
       files which were modified from all parents.

   --cc
       This flag implies the -c option and further compresses the patch output by 
       omitting uninteresting hunks whose contents in the parents have only two 
       variants and the merge result picks one of them without modification.
```

Comment: This kinda sorta works. I still see a bunch of changes that were only introduced by one of the merge heads, I'm not sure if maybe it's because I have 2 merge commits in a row? 
I am seeing all the uninteresting conflict resolutions (which were solved by kdiff3) and the interesting ones. I do notice that the interesting ones are prefixed with ++ as opposed to + or -

Comment: it doesn't show the resolution diffs if the resolution is the same as base.

Comment: in fact, it doesn't show any diff if the resolution is the same as either party's changes

Comment: It works. Can refer [this detailed blog](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/02/21/reviewing-merge-commits/). And on a side note, `git show <COMMIT> --stat` still shows the full changed files

Answer (score 29):

The more recent (2022, nine years later) option is:

```
git log --remerge-diff
```

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git log --remerge-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/90b7153806af46ca62b85a92a2810015be2453d4/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> shows the difference from mechanical merge result and the result that is actually recorded in a merge commit.

See [commit 0dec322](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dec322d31db3920872f43bdd2a7ddd282a5be67), [commit 0d83d82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d83d8240ddb3f54da44563b73527dbc50c4ed22), [commit 20323d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20323d104ec389505e83b9376c8ecab94e852fb8), [commit 95433ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95433eeed9eac439eb21eb30105354b15e71302e), [commit 6054d1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6054d1aac36d5769461fb73b15326a900e53edb9), [commit a28d094](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a28d094ac276da2f6dd8132355baaedf685342ef), [commit 24dbdab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24dbdab50ddaadf6a7abaf5537e0dad36d91e49a), [commit 35f6967](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35f6967161860cb5c067e961b7283e8389ff0726), [commit 7b90ab4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b90ab467a658b2fb1b7c15c7d634e06f35f4ef2), [commit db757e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db757e8b8d5527c195c461a04ec35d141ddea48e) (02 Feb 2022) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 5046831](https://github.com/git/git/commit/504683162642c0db86c844ea37cad339f928ea9c) (21 Dec 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 90b7153](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90b7153806af46ca62b85a92a2810015be2453d4), 16 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`show, log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db757e8b8d5527c195c461a04ec35d141ddea48e): provide a --remerge-diff capability
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> When this option is specified, **we remerge all (two parent) merge commits and diff the actual merge commit to the automatically created version**, in order to show how users:
>
> - removed conflict markers,
> - resolved the different conflict versions, and
> - potentially added new changes** outside of conflict regions in order to resolve semantic merge problems (or, possibly, just to hide other random changes).
>
> This capability works by creating a temporary object directory and marking it as the primary object store.
> This makes it so that any blobs or trees created during the automatic merge are easily removable afterwards by just deleting all objects from the temporary object directory.
>
> There are a few ways that this implementation is suboptimal:
>
> - `log --remerge-diff` becomes slow, because the temporary object directory can fill with many loose objects while running
> - the log output can be muddied with misplaced "**warning: cannot merge binary files**" messages, since [`ll-merge.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/db757e8b8d5527c195c461a04ec35d141ddea48e/ll-merge.c) unconditionally writes those messages to stderr while running instead of allowing callers to manage them.
> - important conflict and warning messages are simply dropped; thus for conflicts like modify/delete or rename/rename or file/directory which are not representable with content conflict markers, there may be no way for a user of `--remerge-diff` to know that there had been a conflict which was resolved (and which possibly motivated other changes in the merge commit).
> - when fixing the previous issue, note that some unimportant conflict and warning messages might start being included.
>   We should instead make sure these remain dropped.
>   Subsequent commits will address these issues.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/db757e8b8d5527c195c461a04ec35d141ddea48e/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L37):

> ### `--diff-merges=(off|none|on|first-parent|1|separate|m|combined|c|dense-combined|cc|remerge|r)`

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/db757e8b8d5527c195c461a04ec35d141ddea48e/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L67-L78):

> ### `--diff-merges=remerge:`
>
> ### `--diff-merges=r:`
>
> ### `--remerge-diff:`
>
> With this option, two-parent merge commits are remerged to
> create a temporary tree object -- potentially containing files
> with conflict markers and such.
>
> A diff is then shown between
> that temporary tree and the actual merge commit.
>
> The output emitted when this option is used is subject to change, and
> so is its interaction with other options (unless explicitly
> documented).

---

Note that one of the commits above is somewhat reverted with With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022):

See [commit 624a935](https://github.com/git/git/commit/624a93507ed3af41506bb4878c43ed3d33be287e) (02 Mar 2022) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8b44e05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b44e05abf256c5c43116b983719cafca2934952), 13 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`merge-ort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/624a93507ed3af41506bb4878c43ed3d33be287e): exclude messages from inner merges by default
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> merge-recursive would only report messages from inner merges when the `GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY` was set to 5.  Do the same for `merge-ort`.
>
> Note that somewhat reverts [0d83d82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d83d8240ddb3f54da44563b73527dbc50c4ed22) ("`merge-ort`: mark conflict/warning messages from inner merges as omittable", 2022-02-02, Git v2.36.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90b7153806af46ca62b85a92a2810015be2453d4) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45fe28c951c3e70666ee4ef8379772851a8e4d32)) based on two facts:
>
> - This commit basically removes the showing of messages from inner merges as well, at least by default.
>   The only difference is that users can request to get them back by turning up the verbosity.
> - Messages from inner merges are specially annotated since [4a3d86e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a3d86e1bb67bea71a481b4cb1860295b97d044a) ("`merge-ort`: make informational messages from recursive merges clearer", 2022-02-17, Git v2.36.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3db182886fccb2220b8aa0a2389cf1c2e12aadb) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/715d08a9e51251ad8290b181b6ac3b9e1f9719d7)).
>   The ability to distinguish them from outer merge comments make them less problematic to include, and easier for humans to parse.

Comment: thanks for you answer. can you help me put that into practice? imagine i have merge commit SHA 111, i want: to see detailed conflict person was facing before finishing his merge (for ex list of files, or 3 way diff like 111^1 merge_base 111^2) and then - precisely how he resolved that conflict (your answer). so basically i want to study his actions: i want to compare his initial conflict to how he has resolved it. it is possible in git? thx

Comment: @Max Start with `git log --remerge-diff 111^!`: a log limited to 111, but which should show you the difference from mechanical merge result and the result that is actually recorded in a merge commit (111).

Answer (score 0):

Slight bikeshed: you could use diff3 or kdiff3 to see the merge in reverse, particularly if it was a (git style) 'evil' merge, where a secondary change was introduced to resolve the conflict.  (watch out for an exploding head trying to see how it 'backs out' the changes;-)

Obviously the 'base' commit would be the merged commit.