# How to check if a merge commit contains manual changes (e.g. resolved conflicts)?

Tags: git, merge, git-commit

How can I find out if there were conflicts when merging a branch and what shenanigans did the person have to do to resolve those conflicts?

`git log -p` seems to show empty diffs for all merge commits, regardless whether they have manual changes or not.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15277708/244297

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) produces a [*combined diff*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#_combined_diff_format) for a merge commit by default, which will contain only the lines that changed as part of the conflict resolution.

```
git show <merge_commit_sha1>
```

`git log` takes the `--cc` option to produce combined diffs for merge commits. For example, to find all merge commits with manual changes you can use:

```
git log -p --cc --min-parents=2
```

and look for commits with diffs.

Comment: Does this show spurious differences if a different version of Git was used to create the merge commit, creating a slightly different merge if there is sufficient ambiguity?

Comment: I have 2 merges with code changes (as confirmed with TIG manual inspection).

one of them "git show" has diff output, one does not. :( not a reliable solution for me.

maybe one was automatic conflict resolved vs manual. not sure.