# How can I see what "previous resolution" git applied?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict, git-rerere

When cherry-picking a commit with similar resolutions to a previously resolved patch I sometime see git saying it tried to re-apply what I'd done earlier. I believe this is the `rerere` component of git.

```
$ git cherry-pick ...
error: could not apply a123f6c424... [commit message]
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
Resolved 'path/to/file.c' using previous resolution.
```

The problem is I don't trust my previous resolution. **How can I see what the "previous resolution" did?** I.e. the diff of just the conflicting areas.

I know I can re-do the merge completely with the following commands. However, I don't want to completely throw away the previous work, just review and validate it.

```
git rerere forget path/to/file.c
git checkout -m path/to/file.c
# Resolve. e.g., git mergetool
```

The following questions are similar but are for merge commits, not conflicts in general or uncommitted changes.

- [How do you see / show a git merge conflict resolution that was done, given a merge commit SHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277708/how-do-you-see-show-a-git-merge-conflict--resolution-that-was-done-given-a-mer)
- [How to check if a merge commit contains manual changes (e.g. resolved conflicts)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253550/how-to-check-if-a-merge-commit-contains-manual-changes-e-g-resolved-conflicts)

Comment: did you already try with a `git diff`, maybe at the cherry pick and now for that file?

Comment: Oh, so it does. While `CHERRY-PICKING`, `git diff` shows just a small set of changes from both parents (two columns of `+`/`-`). I can still compare the absolute changes with `git diff HEAD`. Thanks, @DaemonPainter!