# How to inspect manual conflict resolution in merge commits where the resolution is performed cleanly using one of the parents

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Consider the following git log with the following commits

```
6752364 *   Merge branch 'java-branch'
        |\  
b9e9e66 | * Add an unrelated file
14a7cb9 | * Change favorite language to Java
7b07a43 * | Change favorite language to C#
        |/  
8788146 * C++ is my favorite programming language
```

[You can clone the repo](https://github.com/henriquenj/git-show-conflict-example), I made as example for this question.

My goal is to inspect what merge conflict resolution was made in the merge commit 6752364. For instance, I did this merge so I know that I was prompted for conflict resolution on the `readme.md` file which I did using Meld. I selected "Java" version over "C#" version. I can't see this decision recorded anywhere in the merge commit (not in a way a can easily check at least, more on this later). All I can check is the final state of the file.

There are [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15277708/1335511) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45253550/1335511) in StackOverflow regarding this problem that simply say that I should use `git show` to inspect what kind of resolution was performed. However my `git show` provides me with this output:

```
commit 6752364571d0e9c89ddbb3bd287af2e26eb23e59 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Merge: 7b07a43 b9e9e66
Author: Henrique Jung <henriquenj@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Oct 4 21:18:54 2020 +0200

    Merge branch 'java-branch'
```

I speculate that `git show` is only useful if I had solved the conflict using neither parent commit, but rather a third version not available on any of them (like writing "Haskell" on Meld). How can I inspect a merge commit where the conflict resolution is done using one of the versions "cleanly" i.e. picking parent A or parent B directly? Where is my preference for "Java" over "C#" recorded?

My git version is 2.25.1.

---

Maybe you are thinking: well I can just look at [the commit on GitHub](https://github.com/henriquenj/git-show-conflict-example/commit/6752364571d0e9c89ddbb3bd287af2e26eb23e59) or maybe gitg which shows me the diff. But there's a catch: it shows the *whole* diff. It shows an unrelated file that was never part of the conflict resolution in the first place. So I could inspect the resolution this way, but for big merges it would add a lot of noise, I would be reviewing both  branches again.

This question arose when I was reviewing a big merge with lots of conflict resolution and all the answers that involved `git show` proved to not show what I wanted. The only way I could reliably check which files had conflicts solved manually was to *redo the merge locally*. Clearly there must be a better way.

Comment: Git doesn't record any such metadata, the merge commit just contains the resolved tree and pointers to the parent commits.

Comment: Use `git show -m` to get a diff against each of the two parents of the merge. (And/or, see [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64199454/1256452).)

Comment: With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), `git log --remerge-diff` will show you what you have done in your merge resolution! See [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71181334/6309).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
merge=6752364571d0e9c89ddbb3bd287af2e26eb23e59
git checkout $merge^1
git merge $merge^2
git diff $merge
```

will do it if you're not using auto-reuse of recorded conflict resolutions; if you are, add `-c rerere.enabled=false` as an git option on the merge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess redoing the merge locally is the best option. Thanks for providing the commands in a clear way.